# Is there a way of naming conventions for a specific identifier?

Tags: python, function, conventions

So I have been set this task for revision and I am unsure as to what the question is implying:

Because identifiers in a programming language cannot contain any spaces, programmers use conventions when stating the names of variables and subroutines. Popular conventions include PascalCase (used in these tutorials), camelCase, kebab-case and snake_case. Write a function that takes three parameters, the two parts of an identifier, the convention required and outputs the identifier.​

E.g. Shields Up in kebab-case: shields-up - All letters are in lowercase. Each word is separated with a dash.​

snake_case shields_up - All letters are in lowercase. Each word is separated with an underscore​

camelCase: shieldsUp - All letters are in lowercase except the first letter of the second word.​

PascalCase: ShieldsUp - Only the first letter of each word is in uppercase.

I assume that the code is asking for the identifier to be displayed in each of these conventions.
I have tired looking up ways to turn a string into camelCase but that is as far as I have got.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!
Thanks

Comment: If I pass in the string `"Shields up"` and specify `camelCase`, then what you'd want to do is (1) split the input string into individual words, (2) decapitalize the first word, (3) capitalize every other word, (4) join them back together without spaces.

Comment: I would expect for such a function to take two arguments (the identifier to reformat and the convention), but from your problem description it looks like the identifier will always be two words, split across two arguments. There will probably be a method header provided to you, which should fill you in on what's the expected input format.

Comment: How will the parameters be passed to the function(s)? As a string containing (potentially) multiple words separated by some delimiter? As a list of words? As multiple arguments? We need 2 things. More information about the task and some effort from you - i.e., the code you've written so far and are struggling with

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy unfortunately the question that is showed in the main post is the only information I have been given. Tbh it must be something simple as it has been given to people in my class that have never coded before, but the way the question has been written makes no sense

Comment: @JCaesar I have no idea, I have given all the task information that i have. I assume that I need to create an input for the user to enter the two words as the identifier. I have no idea what this question is actually asking me to do as it is so abstract so honestly i have no code worth showing at the moment. sorry

Comment: The only thing questionable here seems to be what "outputs the identifier" means. Does it mean "returns" (as in the function's return value) or does it mean prints to stdout. Other than that, it seems pretty well-defined and simple enough to write a function such as `def formatIdentifier(s1, s2, convention)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, a simple approach for camelCase would be:

```py
>>> def conventionalIdentifier(str1, str2, convention):
...   if(convention == 'camelcase'):
...     return str1.lower() + str2.capitalize()
...   else: #similarly for the rest
...     pass
...
>>> print(conventionalIdentifier('hello', 'there', 'camelcase'))
helloThere
```

From what I gather, the question specifies that you take two parts of an identifier, i.e. you just have to put two strings together in a particular format.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than what i have read before, thank you. I assume i could use the same layout for the other two conventions. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

This may look like a lot of code for something so trivial but it's designed to show how you can modularise the approach thus making it more extensible should you need to add other styles.

Furthermore, this allows the user to pass multiple words that need to be constructed into the specified style. Rather than call different functions, just call one with a parameter indicating the required style.

```
def kebab(args):
    return '-'.join([arg.lower() for arg in args])

def snake(args):
    return '_'.join([arg.lower() for arg in args])

def camel(args):
    output = [args[0].lower()]
    for arg in args[1:]:
        output.append(arg[0].upper() + arg[1:].lower())
    return ''.join(output)

def pascal(args):
    output = []
    for arg in args:
        output.append(arg[0].upper() + arg[1:].lower())
    return ''.join(output)

CONVENTION = {'k': kebab, 's': snake, 'c': camel, 'p': pascal}

def process(c, args):
    if (func := CONVENTION.get(c.lower(), None)):
        return func(args)
    return None

print(process('s', ['My', 'name','is','jake']))
```